# How can I enforce cascade delete relationship between two lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-365, lookup-column, visual-studio-2013

I created a Sharepoint 2013 app and I am trying to connect two lists with a lookup. If I set `RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Cascade"` on the lookup field the deploy of the app fails even if I also set `Indexed="true"`.

I am developing the app with Visual Studio.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to enforce cascade delete relationship?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue when trying to set the property in the column definition I deploy with my app, however I have been able to specify this property in the "Field" element inside the schema.xml file for the list template that I deploy along with my app. However, it does not seem to be preforming the cascade delete, even with the Indexed="true", and EnforceUniqueValues="True" also specified.

Any progress made by anyone on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have found a solution to this problem.

I had the same problem, trying to set the RelationshipDeleteBehavior (xml) when creating the field. I managed to set the RelationshipDeleteBehavior if I updated the field while setting the contenttype to the list.

So basically I created a function that uses ctx and item as arguments. Then I used it to get the listId and list, I used that to get the ContentType (that I shall add to my list).

Then I get each field of the list and setting update to true, and then I get the schemaXml for each field and replace the `/>` with `'Indexed="TRUE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Restrict" />'`.

For example:

```
var schemaXml = field.get_schemaXml();
schemaXml = schemaXml.replace("/>", ' Indexed="TRUE" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Restrict" />');
field.set_schemaXml(schemaXml);
field.update();
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed problems with the lookup/relationship behavior attribute when a feature is not deployed in the correct dependency order. If a list is deployed before its dependency (another list), the constraint is not implemented. Take a look at this reference for more information:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/11/sharepoint-app-list-lookup-delete.html

I hope this helps.